# Select from (select ....) using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

How do you write the following in Hibernate HQL?

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   example_table 
        ORDER  BY table_date DESC) AS oo 
GROUP  BY table_date;
```

HQL :

```sql
SELECT o 
FROM   (SELECT op 
        FROM   example_table op 
        ORDER  BY table_date DESC) o 
GROUP  BY table_date DESC;
```

The error I'm getting

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 
( near line 1, column 15 [SELECT o FROM (SELECT op FROM za.co.paygate.intranet.database.model.FinTrans op WHERE clientId = :clientId AND finTransDate BETWEEN :monthStart AND :monthEnd ORDER BY finTransDate DESC) o GROUP BY clientTermId];
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
 ( near line 1, column 15 [SELECT o FROM (SELECT op FROM za.co.paygate.intranet.database.model.FinTrans op WHERE clientId = :clientId AND finTransDate BETWEEN :monthStart AND :monthEnd ORDER BY finTransDate DESC) o GROUP BY clientTermId]
```

Comment: Sub-queries in the `FROM` clause are not supported - neither in HQL nor JPQL (including the criteria API). Try to restructure the query to exclude the requirement to have a sub-query in the `FROM` clause or have Hibernate execute this native query directly on the database like `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("Your Query Statement")`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard HQL. What you are using is native SQL. So createSQLQuery for quering instead of createQuery in you code.